# My model is giving a classification report for only one class

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation, unet-neural-network

Classification Report:
precision    recall  f1-score   support

discbulge       1.00      0.96      0.98   5898240
herniation       0.00      0.00      0.00         0
normal       0.00      0.00      0.00         0

```
accuracy                           0.96   5898240
```

macro avg       0.33      0.32      0.33   5898240
weighted avg       1.00      0.96      0.98   5898240

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.Thank you all.I need more insight

my code is here

```
import os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D, Concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define U-Net architecture
def unet():
    inputs = Input(shape=(height, width, channels))

    # Encoder
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(inputs)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)

    conv2 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(pool1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)

    # Decoder
    up1 = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(pool2)
    up1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(up1)
    up1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(up1)
    concat1 = Concatenate(axis=-1)([conv2, up1])

    up2 = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(concat1)
    up2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(up2)
    up2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(up2)
    concat2 = Concatenate(axis=-1)([conv1, up2])

    outputs = Conv2D(num_classes, (1, 1), padding='valid', activation='softmax')(concat2)

    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    return model

# Set up dataset paths and parameters
image_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/opp/lumbar/Images'
label_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/opp/lumbar/Masks'
#output_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/files/Segmented_Images'
num_classes = 3  # Number of segmentation classes (IVD, PE, TS, AAP)
height = 256  # Image height
width = 256  # Image width
channels = 3  # Number of image channels

# Define functions to load and preprocess images and labels
def load_and_preprocess_image(image_path):
    img = Image.open(image_path)
    img = img.resize((width, height))
    img = np.array(img) / 255.0  # Normalize image
    return img

def load_and_preprocess_label(label_path):
    img = Image.open(label_path)
    img = img.resize((width, height))
    img = img.convert('L')  # Convert to grayscale
    img = np.array(img)
    # Perform label encoding
    encoded_labels = np.zeros((height, width, num_classes))
    for c in range(num_classes):
        encoded_labels[:, :, c] = (img == c).astype(int)
    return encoded_labels

# Load and preprocess the dataset
image_filenames = os.listdir(image_dir)
label_filenames = os.listdir(label_dir)

images = []
labels = []

for img_file, lbl_file in zip(image_filenames, label_filenames):
    img_path = os.path.join(image_dir, img_file)
    lbl_path = os.path.join(label_dir, lbl_file)

    # Load and preprocess the image
    image = load_and_preprocess_image(img_path)
    images.append(image)

    # Load and preprocess the label
    label = load_and_preprocess_label(lbl_path)
    labels.append(label)

images = np.array(images)
labels = np.array(labels)

# Split dataset into training and validation sets
train_images, val_images, train_labels, val_labels = train_test_split(images, labels, test_size=0.2)

# Build and compile the U-Net model
model = unet()
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
history = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, batch_size=16, epochs=10, validation_data=(val_images, val_labels))
```

Comment: We do not take external links for code, your code should be in your question as text.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy thanks for the clarification.here is my code